# SQL Server Data Tools not available after installed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ssrs-2008, msbi

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server 2014. I want to learn MSBI, so I have installed the SQL Server Data Tools from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429392.aspx

After the installation process, I coudn't find the SSDT from the start menu.

[image]

But it shown in the control panel:

[image]

And when I check in Visual Studio, there it is also not available.

Comment: I don't know what that link is. Try this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt. I suggest SSDT for VS 2017 (Preview)

Comment: Go to `services.msc` and check if you can see `SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES`. Also please download and install from here if possible : https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Comment: No @Prabhat G, I can't see any SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm already installed Visual Studio 2013, but in that link they told that SSDTs for VS 2016 and 2017. Is it ok?

Comment: @DineshDB: then installation is corrupt. Download and install from the link I've given

Comment: Ok @PrabhatG, the download process was going on, I'll update after trying that

Comment: Thank You @PrabhatG, Its working perfect... And I start learning.. Can you please put this as your answer. It will help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this answer may help someone. The credits goes to [Prabhat G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5470214/prabhat-g)

Go to `services.msc` and check if you can see `SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES`.

If the service not available there, then **installation is corrupted**.

Download and install from the link I've given below

[microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42313](http://microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42313)

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps, but i tried opening a new project in visual studio 2013 instead of visual studio 2012 and found the ssdt tools